# Insert values from CSV file into DATABASE column according to unique ID

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a `CSV` file such as:
`file.csv`

```
id,firstName
1234,john
2222,jane
4567,jim
```

and I have a table `'People'` in my database such as:

```
| id       | lastName       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1234     | doe            |
| 4567     | smith          |
| 2222     | doe            |
```

I would like to add a new column `'firstName'` to the table and use the values from the `CSV` file with the unique `id` number,

```
| id       | lastName       | firstName     |
| -------- | -------------- | --------------
| 1234     | doe            | john          |   
| 4567     | smith          | jim           |   
| 2222     | doe            | jane          |
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the CSV file into a temporary table, which you then merge into the `People` table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE firstNames (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(100)
);

LOAD TABLE INFILE "file.csv"
INSERT INTO firstNames;

ALTER TABLE People ADD COLUMN firstName VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;

UPDATE People AS p
JOIN firstNames AS f ON p.id = f.id
SET p.firstName = f.firstName;
```